# Reprogramming interrupt in c/asm x86

Tags: assembly, x86, interrupt

My problem is that I have to reprogram interrupts without using system libraries like dos.h, so I can't use functions like getvect or setvect. I have made working program in C (with asm inserts) but it's using DOS functions. How to make it without dos.h and use asm instead?

I thought about writing program into fixed place in memory and then change adres in interrupt vector table but I have no idea how to do this - especially that program is mostly in C.

I have to reprogram system clock interrupt and LPT interrupt. Timer of the system clock has been speeded up so every few times I have to generate original system clock interrupt.

Comment: Wow, this brings back memories of DOS programming 20-25 years ago. What platform are you trying to do this on? 16-bit MS-DOS (or Dosbox)?

Comment: For me it brings back 2 years old memories :) OSDev is addictive..

Comment: I firstly used DOS in win98 but now i use FreeDos

Comment: I [reprogrammed INT 0x20](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/284797/hello-world-in-less-than-20-bytes/285684#285684) as answer to an unrelated question here at SO :)

Comment: Minimal 16-bit example: https://github.com/cirosantilli/x86-bare-metal-examples/blob/9a24f92f36a45abb3f8c37aafc0c3ee9b15563ab/interrupt.S#L71 Minimal PIT example: https://github.com/cirosantilli/x86-bare-metal-examples/blob/9a24f92f36a45abb3f8c37aafc0c3ee9b15563ab/in_pit.S

Answer (score 4):

As far as I remember, interrupt table started at 0000:0000h . There are 4 bytes per interrupt record: 2 bytes for segment 2 for offset.

```
xor ax, ax
mov es, ax

mov bx, interrupt_number
mov ax, cs
mov es[bx*4], ax
mov es[bx*4+2], offset yourSubroutine
```

It should be something like this, though I do not remember very precisely

Comment: That seems correct. Only thing to keep in mind is to save the original values first so when you want to call it or when exiting the app you can reference the original handler.

Comment: Correct, ssg. You should always save original values and restore them back as soon as your program hits int 20h or mov ax, 0x4c int 21h :)

Comment: Ok, but my problem is how to get adres of my program, especially that it's not normal asm - my program is 70% in C.

Comment: micmax93, you mean how to get offset of your function ?

Comment: As far as i remember the address, how many bytes of interrupt are quite machine depended, but the asm code looks legit.

Comment: Function address can be obtained by a pointer to the function

Comment: Thanks, ziq. It should be correct. This code is burned in my visionary memory :)

Comment: Thanks ziq. I didn't thought it would be this simple :)

Comment: Maybe one more think about rewriting interrupt. If this interrupt use some resident program, than switch of interrupts before rewriting vector and switch on again after that. If software interrupt is happend after segment override and offset is still old, than invalid interrupt call can be performed, so switch-off interrupts first.